# What's the best way to debug JavaScript on IBM Connections?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've been building OpenSocial gadgets for IBM Connections and notice that the JavaScript is pre-fetched, minified and concatenated into a single file by the IBM Connections server.

This is great for production, but having already enabled developer mode in IBM Connections, it would be great if each JS file wasn't pushed onto a single line.

- Is there a setting to prevent the minification?
- Does IBM Connections generate a source map so that the original JS can be regenerated?
- Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any source maps, but the dojo loader can help you out a lot. Add ?debug=true to a URL to have all JS files fetched separately, unminified. Use debug=dojo and the files will still be concatenated, but unminified.

If your URL has a # in it, place the ?debug=dojo *before* the #.

Comment: This is all kinds of awesome. I'm very happy to know this.